# How do you make an IMAGE move independent of the elements around it using CSS3 Transition?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to use a CSS3 transition to make the image inside this `<div>` move 10 pixels upward when the `<div>` is hovered over. It works great in Firefox, but when I view it in Chrome and Safari, the `<h3>` and `<p>` elements jitter up and down a bit.

This is my CSS:

```css
.feature-table #box {
    width: 325px;
    height: 372px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    float: left;
}

.feature-table a {
    display: block;
    width: 325px;
    height: 372px;
}

.feature-table a img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-top: 54px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.feature-table a: hover img {
    padding-top: 44px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.feature-table a h3 {
    font-family: 'GothamBold', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #3d3d3d;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 25px;
}

.feature-table a: hover h3 {
    color: #f6ce4f;
}

.feature-table a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.feature-table p {
    font-family: 'GothamLight', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14.5px;
    color: #949494;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 28px;
}

.feature-table .caret {
    border-top: 5px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #fff;
    border-left: 5px solid #ffc235;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

This is part of my HTML:

```
<div id="box">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="images/payment_icon.png" width="114" height="115" border="0" />
        <h3>Customizable Campaign Pages</h3>
        <p>Tell your story with images, video, rich text and social updates<b class="caret"></b></p>
    </a>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It may be a performance issue because you're animating 2 different properties that affect the current layout.
The ideal solution would be to use a certain prop that doesn't affect the other elements. In your case, this can be done with the `top` property, after setting the image's position to `relative` :

```
a img{
    position : relative;
    top : 0;
}
a:hover img{
    top : -4px;
}
```

Here's a working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/p7Lxz/

Comment: I ended up adding inline-block to this element.

    .feature-table a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 325px;
    height: 372px;
    }


And then making the img element position absolute and it worked perfect!